# max_depth vs. max_leaf_nodes in scikit-learn's RandomForestClassifier

Tags: random-forest, scikit-learn

What's the difference, if any at all, between `max_depth` and `max_leaf_nodes` in sklearn's [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forest) for a simple binary classification problem?

If the model always grows trees in a symetric fashion, one would assume setting `max_depth` = 5 is equivalent to setting `max_leaf_nodes` = 32.

The fact that sklearn gives us 2 options suggests that might not be the case.

Comment: A tree of 32 nodes can have a depth far greater than 5.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Is there any documentation on RF grows trees leaf-wise when `max_leaf_nodes` is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @whuber points out in a comment, a 32-leaf tree may have depth larger than 5 (up to 32).  To answer your followup question, yes, when `max_leaf_nodes` is set, `sklearn` builds the tree in a best-first fashion rather than a depth-first fashion.

From [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) (emphasis added):

> **max_leaf_nodes : *int, default=None***
>
> Grow trees with `max_leaf_nodes` **in best-first fashion**. Best nodes are defined as relative reduction in impurity. If None then unlimited number of leaf nodes.

and in [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/786c4e5e39648127f41913d4e0c53672a44306f0/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L399):

```py
        # snipped from much earlier, line 231 in the permalink above:
        max_leaf_nodes = -1 if self.max_leaf_nodes is None else self.max_leaf_nodes
        ...
        # Use BestFirst if max_leaf_nodes given; use DepthFirst otherwise
        if max_leaf_nodes < 0:
            builder = DepthFirstTreeBuilder(
                 ...
            )
        else:
            builder = BestFirstTreeBuilder(
                ...
            )
```